# Wiener entropy and Shannon entropy

Tags: time-series, entropy

1. I would like to calculate the Wiener entropy of a time-series on a spreadsheet, using a moving-window. I know that it is related to the ratio of the geometric average and the mean average, but what is the exact formula please? I have not been able to find it.
2. What would be the best (=easiest) way to otherwise calculate the entropy of a time series as above, for example the Shannon entropy? The time series is just a series of say twenty numbers, not a list of probabilities.
3. If calculating the Wiener and Shannon entropies does not produce exactly the same number, what is the formula for converting the Wiener entropy into the Shannon entropy?
4. I would be interested to hear of any other kinds of entropy that can be calculated for a time series (with a moving window) on a spreadsheet.

Comment: The formula is in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_flatness). It is based on the power spectrum, which is based on the Fourier Transform of the signal.  To perform FTs with a spreadsheet, you need to write a macro.  You cannot convert one form of entropy to another--although they share the term "entropy," they are different quantities.